# difference between '$(<%= DDL.ID %>) & $('<%= DDL.ID %>')

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I was trying to bind an event to drop down list since yesterday nothing helped went to JavaScript chat room no one was able to find a fix to my problem, but then I somehow tried to bind my drop down list as following

```js
$('<%= ddl.ID %>').bind('change',myfunction);
```

to

```js
$(<%= ddl.ID %>).bind('change',myfunction);
```

and it started working, any idea ?

**EDIT**

Sorry Its not working on IE :(

Comment: <%= ddl.ID %> return ID but if you want to use this control in content page or user control id changed so you have to use `<%= ddl.ClientID %>` instead of `'ID'`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

jQuery uses `CSS selector` like syntax.

For `ID Selector` it needs to be prefix with `#` symbol. Example, `$('#DOMElementId')`

Check jQuery [**Selector list**](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

In your case correct one should be

```
$('#<%= ddl.ID %>').bind('change',myfunction) // if you have no master page or 
                                              //ClientIDMode="static"
```

or

```
$('#<%= ddl.ClientID %>').bind('change',myfunction)
```

Answer (score 4):

The [jQuery function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/) needs a string as selector.

The latter syntax has no meaning, except

- if your string is a javascript variable (for example `document.body` or `myvar` if you defined `myvar`).
- if your `ddl.ID` string contains the quotes (you may have created it as `ddl.ID = "\"#id\"";`)

It's possible you fixed a bug by another bug rendering ineffective this line in your code.

Answer (score 2):

You should probably use `ClientID` instead

`$('#<%= ddl.ClientID %>').bind('change', myfunction);`

Answer (score 1):

best option is

```
$('#'+'<%= ddl.ClientID %>').bind('change',myfunction);
```

it works even you use this control in user control or content page

```
$('#'+'<%= ddl.ClientID %>').change(myfunction);
```