# asp:RadioButton and javascript function $find()

Tags: javascript, asp.net

```
<asp:RadioButton ID="myButton" Text="Option" GroupName="group" runat="server" />
```

Why in this case javascript function call `$find('<%= myButton.ClientID %>')` return `null`? I need to detect/change value in client javascript. `$find()` should be shortcut for `Sys.Application.findComponent()`.

UPDATE: There is no problem with ID, i tried $find() in chrome console with real rendered id and still getting null. And i want to get Ajax control, not DOM element.

Comment: What library you are talking about? jQuery or ASP.Net ajax library?

Comment: My previous answer would help you

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12402823/difference-between-ddl-id-ddl-id/12402942#12402942

Comment: @fanosek, an `<asp:RadioButton>` server tag will result in a DOM element, not a component, unless you have an extender attached to it. In that case, you should pass the behavior id of the extender to `$find()`, not the id of the element (they're not always the same).

Comment: how to determine which control render as component and which a DOM only? I need to change radiobuttons checks in group dynamically on client in javascript

Comment: You usually know a given control will generate a component because you create and attach an extender in the first place. If you don't do that, then the control will be rendered as one or more DOM elements. You should use `$get()` with those, see my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set clientIdMode to static if your don't have multiple instances of it:

```
<asp:RadioButton ClientIDMode="static" ID="myButton" Text="Option" GroupName="group" runat="server" />
```

OR

You need to use ClientID to access find your button. But the script must be on the same page.

```
var radioButton = $('#<%= myButton.ClientID %>');
```

Comment: `$find()` is part of the ASP.NET AJAX library, not jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

You can `directly` assess element by its id and you do `not` need to using `find`, you just need `id` selector as id is unique for html elements.

```
$(function(){
    var myButton = $('#<%= myButton.ClientID %>');
    alert(myButton.id);

    //with javascript
    myButton = document.getElementById('#<%= myButton.ClientID %>');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your DOM is ready when you're trying to get component?

Try something like this:

```
window.onload = function() {
    alert( $find('myButton') );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[$find()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397441.aspx) tries to find a ASP.NET AJAX component from its behavior id.

Since you're looking for a DOM element, not a component, you should use [$get()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397717.aspx) instead:

```
var yourButton = $get("<%= myButton.ClientID %>");
```